# RingoJS javascript - get user input on console

Tags: javascript, rhino, commonjs, ringojs

When using Rhino or RingoJS, one can use `print` on the console REPL to print output (`alert` is not available).

What can be used to read user input on the console, instead of `prompt`?

Is there somewhere I can find information on these conventions, what APIs are available in Rhino and/or RingoJS, or is there a CommonJS guide they are adhering to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that currently there is no standard (widely supported) way of reading bytes from the standard input stream.  With Rhino you could simply use the Java "System.in" input stream; RingoJS does apparently implement the [System module](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/System/1.0).

It looks like the [CommonJS group](http://www.commonjs.org/) is still working on a [draft of the "System" specification which includes a "stdin" object](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/System#System_Interface) which should be an input stream and behave just like a file opened in "r" mode; such an object should also [include a "`read()`"](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/IO/A#Stream) method.  Note however that these are all draft specs and it looks like very few JavaScript environments provide implementations.  In an environment which does implement the System and IO specs you should be able to do something like this:

```javascript
var system = require('system');
system.stdin.read(10); // Read ten bytes.
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation. It does seem somewhat odd then that they don't ship with alert and prompt until specs are finalised. I read about why they don't ship with alert when I was trying to find the alternative. Alert breaks compatibility with old browsers etc.